# Integrate Linkedin from iphone app? shows "-canOpenURL: failed for URL: linkedin://-error: This app is not allowed to query for scheme linkedin"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

Pod File used :

1. https://github.com/tonyli508/LinkedinSwift

created new app in here : https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk

Answer (score 1):

In info.plist , Add App Transport Security setting and allow the arbitrary loads which is a bool. Also add "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" there.

on click,
enable this code

```
let url  = NSURL(string: "linkedin://");
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```

Comment: I've added LIAppId, LSApplicationQueriesSchemes, NSAppTransportSecurity, NSAllowsArbitraryLoads, NSExceptionDomains &  NSIncludesSubdomains in info.plist. Still its not working